# Checking if NamedPipeClientStream has something to read

Tags: c#, named-pipes

I need to check a NamedPipeClientStream to see if there are bytes for it to read before I attempt to read it. The reason for this is because the thread stops on any read operation if there's nothing to read and I simply cannot have that. I must be able to continue even if there's no bytes to read.

I've also tried wrapping it in a StreamReader, which I've seen suggested, but that has the same result.

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(myPipe)
string temp;
while((temp = sr.ReadLine()) != null) //Thread stops in ReadLine
{
    Console.WriteLine("Received from server: {0}", temp);
}
```

I either need for the read operations to *not* wait until there are bytes to read, or a way to check if there are bytes to read before attempting the read operations.

PipeStream does not support the Length, Position or ReadTimout properties or Seek...

Comment: This is a very bad pattern. Structure your code so that there's a reading thread that always tries to read until the stream has ended. Then, make your threads communicate to achieve the logic and control flow you want.

Comment: Or better, use the `Async` functionality and don't have threads that are just spending time *waiting* for I/O to happen.

Answer (score -1):

This is a very bad pattern. Structure your code so that there's a reading thread that always tries to read until the stream has ended. Then, make your threads communicate to achieve the logic and control flow you want.

It is generally not possible to check whether an arbitrary `Stream` has data available. I think it's possible with named pipes. But even if you do that you need to ensure that incoming bytes will be read in a timely manner. There is no event for that. Even if you manage all of this the code will be quite nasty. It will not be easy to mentally verify.

For that reason, simply keep a reading loop alive. You could make that reading loop enqueue the data into a queue (maybe `BlockingCollection`). Then other threads can check that queue for data or wait for data to arrive. The stream will always be drained correctly. You can signal the stream end by enqueueing `null`.

When I say "thread" I mean any primitive that gives you the appearance of a thread. These days you would never use `Thread`. Rather, use `async/await` or `Task`.

Comment: You think a good pattern, in 2018, is to have threads waiting rather than just queueing I/O and taking advantage of Async patterns? Interesting.

Comment: I say "thread" for reasons of simplification. He can use an async method just as well. The structure of the solution stays the same. Generally, I also do think that threads (or tasks) are still an acceptable solution. They can have better dev productivity at possibly negligible memory cost. It is false that async IO is always preferable which you seem to believe. Async IO has a productivity cost.